# Postgres / JDBC with pgjdbc-ng: Writing EAN type to database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm using postgres 12, `PGJDBC-NG 0.8.3`, and `org.clojure/java.jdbc 0.7.10`.

I'm trying to switch my code over from using the standard postgres JDBC implementation (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to pgjdbc-ng (https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) so that I can use the Listen/Notify functionality which stock postgres JDBC lacks.

I have managed to get the basic functionality working but I'm having some trouble inserting EAN13 types into the database (an extension type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/isn.html).

Here is an example table:

```sql
create extension isn;
create table p (barcode ean13 primary key);
insert into p values ('5023652298064');
select barcode from p;
+-----------------+
| barcode         |
|-----------------|
| 502-365229806-4 |
+-----------------+
```

Now in my code, I have a record EAN that I use to insert the eans:

```clj
(defrecord ean [s])

(def ds (doto (PGDataSource.)
          (.setDatabaseUrl "jdbc:pgsql://localhost:5432/web?user=root")))

(jdbc/execute! {:datasource ds}
            ["update products set ean = ? where id = 5242" (db/->ean "5012583002819")])
Execution error (IllegalStateException) at com.impossibl.postgres.types.Type/getParameterFormat (Type.java:318).
type has no supported parameter format: ean13(3767891)
```

This was the code I had for setting the right type in the stock postgres JDBC:

```
(extend-protocol clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLParameter
  ean
  (set-parameter [val ^PreparedStatement stmt ^long i]
    ; The type of this parameter should be PGObject, which is a wrapper provided by
    ; the postgres JDBC driver for types which does not have a corresponding type in
    ; the JDBC interface.
    (.setObject stmt i (doto (PGobject.)
                         (.setType "ean13")
                         (.setValue (.s val))))))
```

but I can't for the life of me figure out how that translates to something working for PGJDBC-NG! What is the correct ISQLParameter extension to get this working?

Comment: I am working through basically the same issue.  What did you do to resolve this?

Comment: I'm afraid that in the end I realized I didn't really need listen/notify, and gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just copy PGobject into your project and import it normally.  Doesn't seem to be much special about it.